# Получить день недели по дате

Tags: java, android

Как узнать день недели по дате?
Есть такой код:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Integer dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

В нем я узнаю день в неделе от 1 до 7.

Проблема в том, что я не могу узнать измененный день в неделе, используя [DatePicker.](http://androiddocs.ru/datepickerdialog-vidzhet-vybora-daty/)
Например, в начальной активности стоит дата 14.07.2017 (день в неделе равен 1, т.к. воскресенье).

Меняю дату на другое число и не могу получить новый день в неделе, получаю старый.

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```